# Does the use of the em dash work here? Should there be a comma after the second em dash?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, commas, em-dash

> Presenting two main aspects of her practice—slow art and language—this exhibition is a coalescence of her enthralment with everyday marvels and her fascination with the intricacies and nuances of languages.

Would a comma need to come after the em dash for this sentence to make sense/be grammatically correct? Or does this sentence just need to be reworded entirely?

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24960/can-a-comma-follow-an-em-dash

Comment: I would say that that answer the question.  No comma, because the em dash replaces the comma.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a comma follow an em dash?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24960/can-a-comma-follow-an-em-dash)